# How to install google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools via composer?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, php-7.2

I'm trying to figure out how to let my users upload files in my Google App Engine app. I'm following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload

It starts with:

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
```

However, that package doesn't exist in any of the vendor directories I've got and I can't figure out what I need to add to my composer.json in order to get this code.

I've got code in other places in my project that will `use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;` but that is a different code base and it doesn't contain the `CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()` function which is what I'm trying to get access to.

[image]

[image]

Here is what my `composer.json` contains:

```
{
  "require": {
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^2.6",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "php-http/message": "^1.6",
    "google/cloud-storage": "^1.9",
    "google/cloud-debugger": "^0.14.2",
    "ext-stackdriver_debugger": "*"
  },
  "name": "",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add `google/appengine-php-sdk` in Your composer.json https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk/blob/master/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php

Comment: Yes! That was it. If you post this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `google/appengine-php-sdk` to your composer.json.

`composer require google/appengine-php-sdk`